# Select * from table show multiple entries

Tags: database, oracle11g

[image]

when i use select * from table the database shows like this. Why is it so ? I have only one entry for each column. It shows repeated times.

Comment: i can't use Resultset now to select from the table in my java program

Comment: the problem is with the 9th column. I removed one column and all works well.

Comment: If you have no constraint then the select will return all rows.  Who can read this mess?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the line size and page size if necessary like this:

```
set linesize 100 pagesize 50
```

you can change the value of `linesize` and `pagesize`  according to you.

or you can try this, it works for me most of the time

```
set lines 256
set trimout on
set space 1
set tab off
```